# Does the frame in which the CMB is isotropic violate the Copernican Principle?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

The Copernican Principle states that Earth is not at a special place in the Universe, and by extension, that there are no "special places" in the Universe (per homogeneity of the universe, aka the cosmological principle). However, the frame in which the CMB is isotropic appears pretty special:

- There is exactly one reference frame in which the CMB is isotropic
- It's independent of the observer's motion
- Every observer agrees which reference frame that is
- It's not trivial, since it makes the CMB simpler (and the CMB underpins much of modern cosmology)

Does the frame in which the CMB is isotropic violate the Copernican Principle? If so, why do we still believe in the Copernican Principle?

Comment: The CMB frame is special to any inhabitant of the universe, as far as I can see. The Earth's frame also is, but only to Earthlings.

Comment: I don't see how that violates the Copernican principle, since the CMB fills the whole universe, it doesn't single out a special place.

Comment: @PM2Ring hmm, good point. I guess it doesn't violate the Copernican Principle then, although it does still look like a "preferred frame". I will need to think about it.

Comment: GR doesn't rule out the existence of special useful frames. Also note that if you're in a properly sealed lab you cannot determine the CMB rest frame, you have to look outside your lab.

Comment: @PM2Ring can you detect the CMB in that sealed lab though? If so, you should be able to determine the CMB rest frame. If not, then the sealed lab hardly seems like a workable lab.

Comment: But that's the point of the sealed lab in GR thought experiments. Eg, the equivalence principle says that in the sealed lab you can't tell whether you're in a uniform gravitational field or undergoing uniform acceleration.

Comment: The Copernican principle claims that the universe is homogeneous and isotropic, not that it is Lorentz invariant. No one said you should be able to move at any velocity and see the same universe.

Comment: @PM2Ring one still can't form hypotheses about things one cannot observe though. For example suppose new physics is discovered that define a preferred reference frame & can only be detected by a special detector. In a sealed lab without that detector, they'd still come to the conclusion that there's no preferred reference frame, wouldn't they?

Comment: @Javier Are you sure? According to my Googling, it's the cosmological principle (not Copernican principle) that claims that the universe is homogeneous & isotropic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMB frame provides a privileged [foliation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliation) of spacetime by spacelike hypersurfaces, essentially by defining universal *cosmic time* via some function $t_c=f(T_\text{CMB})$. A given “slice” $t_c=\mathrm{const}$ could be then interpreted as a *space* part of a spacetime.

Copernican Principle as stated by OP means that “there are no *special places*”. Applied to cosmological models we could identify “places” with points of *space* within a slice $t_c=\mathrm{const}$. And indeed if averaged over sufficiently large scale these slices appear to be homogeneous spaces, every point of it is just like any other point.

We see that **cosmological models that assume spatial homogeneity do satisfy Copernican Principle in the sense outlined above**.

Note, that the “time” part of spacetime is not homogeneous: every moment (on cosmological timescale) is unique and not like the moments before or after, at the very least they differ by having a specific value of CMB temperature.

Comment: *every point of it is just like any other point* wouldn't the point where the CMB is isotropic be special, though?

Comment: One could chose the 4-velocity vector at *any point* of spacetime so that CMB is isotropic. It would be orthogonal to the slice $t=\mathrm{const}$ at this point. In the language of three-dimensional space it means that we can choose an observer passing through any specific point in space at a given moment in time such that this observer sees CMB as isotropic.